# US Currency Format Multiple Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build this simple rent affordability java-script calculator and the issue that I have is the last box the "Rent Affordability TextBox" does not properly format the US currency format until you use the little scrollbars that appear an the text-box and then it will format, I seem to be having some sort on onclick event happening when I do so.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

 <style>
 <!--
.currency {
  padding-left:12px;
}

.currency-symbol {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}  
 //-->
 </style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
function run(){

var PercentageRate = 40;

var Income = parseInt(document.getElementById('YearlyIncome').value);
var Expenses = parseInt(document.getElementById('MonthlyExpenses').value);

var PercentageCalculated = Income / PercentageRate;

document.getElementById('RentAffordability').value = PercentageCalculated - Expenses;

}
</script>


<script> 
 (function($) {
  $.fn.currencyInput = function() {
    this.each(function() {
      var wrapper = $("<div class='currency-input' />");
      $(this).wrap(wrapper);
      $(this).change(function() {
        var min = parseFloat($(this).attr("min"));
        var max = parseFloat($(this).attr("max"));
        var value = this.valueAsNumber;
        if(value < min)
          value = min;
        else if(value > max)
          value = max;
        $(this).val(value.toFixed(2)); 
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.currency').currencyInput();
});

 </script>

<p>Total Yearly Income: <input type="number" class="currency" name="YearlyIncome" id="YearlyIncome"  /></p>

<p>Monthly Expenses: <input type="number" class="currency" name="MonthlyExpenses" id="MonthlyExpenses" /></p>

<p>Rent Affordability: <input type="number" class="currency" name="RentAffordability" id="RentAffordability" /></p>

<button onclick="run()">calculate</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had only applied the `toFixed` to the initialization stage, you need to apply this after the number is calculated too.

`$('#RentAffordability').val((PercentageCalculated - Expenses).toFixed(2));`

You may also wish to add the other conditional stages before applying the `toFixed` such as

```
    var min = parseFloat($(this).attr("min"));
    var max = parseFloat($(this).attr("max"));
    var value = this.valueAsNumber;
    if(value < min)
      value = min;
    else if(value > max)
      value = max;
```

```html
 <style>
 <!--
.currency {
  padding-left:12px;
}

.currency-symbol {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}  
 //-->
 </style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
function run(){

var PercentageRate = 40;

var Income = parseInt(document.getElementById('YearlyIncome').value);
var Expenses = parseInt(document.getElementById('MonthlyExpenses').value);

var PercentageCalculated = Income / PercentageRate;

//document.getElementById('RentAffordability').value = PercentageCalculated - Expenses;
  $('#RentAffordability').val((PercentageCalculated - Expenses).toFixed(2));
}
</script>


<script> 
 (function($) {
  $.fn.currencyInput = function() {
    this.each(function() {
      var wrapper = $("<div class='currency-input' />");
      $(this).wrap(wrapper);
      $(this).change(function() {
        var min = parseFloat($(this).attr("min"));
        var max = parseFloat($(this).attr("max"));
        var value = this.valueAsNumber;
        if(value < min)
          value = min;
        else if(value > max)
          value = max;
        $(this).val(value.toFixed(2)); 
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.currency').currencyInput();
});

 </script>

<p>Total Yearly Income: <input type="number" class="currency" name="YearlyIncome" id="YearlyIncome"  /></p>

<p>Monthly Expenses: <input type="number" class="currency" name="MonthlyExpenses" id="MonthlyExpenses" /></p>

<p>Rent Affordability: <input type="number" class="currency" name="RentAffordability" id="RentAffordability" /></p>

<button onclick="run()">calculate</button>
```